# ActiveMQ Persistent Store Full but memory usage 0

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm seeing this message in my AMQ log

```
[pid: ][ActiveMQ Transport: ssl:///127.0.0.1:56866] 21 Apr 2022 12:36:27  WARN Queue - Usage(default:store:queue://com.queue.error:store) percentUsage=99%, usage=10746143122, limit=10737418240, percentUsageMinDelta=1%;Parent:Usage(default:store) percentUsage=100%, usage=10746143122, limit=10737418240, percentUsageMinDelta=1%: Persistent store is Full, 100% of 10737418240. Stopping producer (ID:scpfnlp001p.dcswins.com-43963-1647218102788-1:38887:1:1) to prevent flooding queue://com.queue.error. See http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html for more info (blocking for: 1202s)
```

This doesn't make sense to me since my queues all have memory usage at 0..

I monitor the queues with JMX and here is what it is reporting.

```
"EnqueueCount":846
"MemoryPercentUsage":0
"ConsumerCount":2
"DequeueCount":846
"ExpiredCount":0
"Name":"com.queue.input.keyword"}
{"QueueSize":42
"EnqueueCount":1690
"MemoryPercentUsage":0
"ConsumerCount":0
"DequeueCount":1686
"ExpiredCount":0
"Name":"com.queue.inflight"}
{"QueueSize":0
"EnqueueCount":840
"MemoryPercentUsage":0
"ConsumerCount":0
"DequeueCount":840
"ExpiredCount":0
"Name":"com.queue.output"}
{"QueueSize":264
"EnqueueCount":77
"MemoryPercentUsage":0
"ConsumerCount":0
"DequeueCount":0
"ExpiredCount":0
"Name":"com.queue.error"}
{"QueueSize":0
"EnqueueCount":845
"MemoryPercentUsage":0
"ConsumerCount":1
"DequeueCount":845
"ExpiredCount":0
"Name":"com.queue.reader.keyword"}
{"QueueSize":4
"EnqueueCount":698
"MemoryPercentUsage":0
"ConsumerCount":1
"DequeueCount":848
"ExpiredCount":0
"Name":"com.queue.reader"}
{"QueueSize":0
"EnqueueCount":849
"MemoryPercentUsage":0
"ConsumerCount":8
"DequeueCount":849
"ExpiredCount":0
"Name":"com.queue.input"}
{"QueueSize":2
"EnqueueCount":843
"MemoryPercentUsage":0
"ConsumerCount":0
"DequeueCount":843
"ExpiredCount":0
"Name":"com.queue.keyword.output"}]
"CurrentStatus":"Good"
"DataDirectory":"\/var\/mqbroker\/bin\/activemq-data"
"Persistent":true
"status":"success"}
```

The output queue can have large objects so I would expect the memoryUsage to be > 0

Here is my destinatio policy

```
  <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="false" optimizedDispatch="true" maxPageSize="1000">
```

Can someone explain why the store would fill up and memory usage be 0.. This make no sense to me